# Where to see smallest size of segmented object in eCognition?

Tags: ecognition

I used ecognition to conduct segmentation, and I'm wondering where I can see the segmentation result, like the smallest size of object segmented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has been a while when you asked it, but maybe useful for some... 
To find the smallest/biggest segment you have to go to: 
Image object Table ( under Image Object menu) 
[image]

'Area' column is not there by default, you need to add it, so right click on the Image object table and choose Configure Image... 
[image]

And then add Area column as it is shown at the last screenshot:[image]

I hope this is something you have been looking for ...

Comment: Hi, ChrisL,thanks so much for helping! I found the area indication in object information, but I don't know how to make the list of all objects areas together to choose the smallest one. Each click on one object can show its area in my project. could you please help me ? Many thanks

Comment: just click on 'area' column name, this will sort descending or ascending. On the screenshot, the smallest polygon is on the top, double clicking on the record will take you straight to it

Comment: Hi ChrisL, it worked! Thanks soooo much many appreciations to your time and help!

Comment: Hi ChrisL, sorry to disturb again. Just have one question: what's the original unit for area? One object with the area of 'x', if I edit unit to pixel, it's 'x' pixel, and it's 'x' square meters too if editing to square meters. So confused. Many thanks in advance!